Evaluating a classifier's performance on different groups of subjects
I have developed a binary classifier that predicts whether a subject is injured or healthy. I am interested to know whether my model performs better on certain groups of subjects than on others. For example, my holdout data set contains 12 subjects over the age of 30 and 15 subjects 30 years old or younger. My model achieves 0.83 precision/recall for the older group, but achieves 0.57/0.67 precision/recall for the younger group, relative to the physician's diagnosis.
A hypothesis I would like to evaluate is whether my model has different diagnostic performance on the older group subjects than on the younger.
Are there any standard approaches for evaluating model performance on different subsets of subjects? I am considering Fisher's Exact Test, Mann Whitney U-test, DeLong Test, among others. Any examples in published research would be helpful.

Since precision and recall are basically binary outcomes, you could compare the precisions and recalls directly.  However, with the given sample sizes I think you're probably going to have a poor time doing so.
The standard error for a binary variable is
$$ \operatorname{s.e} = \sqrt{\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}} $$
When you take the difference of two proportions, then the standard error is
$$ \sqrt{\operatorname{s.e_1^2} + \operatorname{s.e_2^2}} $$
where the subscripts indicate groups (i.e. $\operatorname{s.e_2^2}$ is the standard error for group 2, squared).  Given the estimated precisions you've stated, the standard error would be roughly 0.17.
$$ \sqrt{\dfrac{0.83(1-0.83)}{12} + \dfrac{0.57(1-0.57)}{15}} \approx0.17$$
Most results would be considered "statistically significant" if the observed difference is larger than 2 standard errors.  For your precision, that doesn't seem to be the case.
But even if it was, the results would give me pause.  These are fairly noisy estimates since the sample sizes are so small.  I would be concerned about possible effects like "The Winner's Curse".  Not only this, but you shouldn't use the data test data to evaluate this hypothesis because that would beTesting hypotheses suggested by the data.
If there is concern about differential performance based on strata, I would probably find a way to get more data from these strata and properly evaluate your hypothesis.

Thank you for the detailed response. Could you explain why you chose precision (0.57) as the probability of the second binomial r.v. and 1-recall as its complement? I'm curious if you're familiar with any publications where the researchers evaluated their model by performing such a statistical test on binary outcomes like accuracy, precision, recall, specificity, etc.

@RoyPhillips I mistakenly typed 1-0.67 when I should have typed 0.57.  See my edited answer.  I'm not going to recommend you a paper where this is done because you haven't seemed to understand my larger point:  Your sample is noisy and you would be testing the hypothesis suggested by the data.

Re: the Winner's curse. These are definitely issues I need to consider more when presenting these findings. This post-hoc analysis aims to have some discussion points about possible effects that are worth evaluating on new data, with adjustments for multiple comparisons. My understanding is that journals like to see statistical tests over just stating some conclusions based on model performance, but that could be misguided. I suppose a more rigorous strategy could be to develop some hypotheses based on the cross-validation of the training data and tests of those hypotheses on the test data

Sorry for the delayed response on the second point - had trouble getting it under the character limit. I'll think about some other ways to assess and present subject-level effects on the model performance
